# v4 androidmanifest.xml file not found

Tags: java, android, xml, intellij-idea, android-manifest

I am working on a project to learn how to use fragments and after inputting all my code, I received an error message stating that the [v4] androidmanifest.xml cannot be found. I went into my project structure settings in IntelliJ to investigate and it turns out that a v4 androidmanifest.xml was never created. I am unsure of how to proceed as this is new to me and there is not a lot of info on the web about this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you chosen to make "Android Application" at the New Project wizard?

Comment: Yes I have done that already.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot with your top-level project structure?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm kind of a beginner. What do you mean by my top-level project structure?

Comment: Files and folders under the root folder of your project

Comment: [http://i.imgur.com/qUXgDff.png](Here you go)

Comment: Why do you need sources of v13 and v4 support libraries if you already have jars attached? they can be dropped from your project.

Comment: They were added automatically. I can go ahead and remove them.

Comment: Yes, please. Also gridlayout can be removed I think

Comment: Yes, I added that by accident. Do you know how I can delete these? IntelliJ isn't providing me with an option to do so that I see.

Edit: Nevermind, I found out how to delete them.

Comment: Right click on a module -> Refactor -> Delete (Safe Delete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer based on comments to close this question:

You have sources of support libraries attached to your project, just delete them by **Right click on a module -> Refactor -> Delete (Safe Delete)**